# PHP, array to string with separator characters

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array like this:

```
Array (
       [3] => 15 
       [30] => 1 
       [1] => 1 )
```

I want to convert it into a string like this:
    $string = "3:15;30:1;1:1;"

Thanks you in advance

Comment: This is trivially easy to do with a simple `foreach($arr as $key => $value)`. Are you having trouble with something in particular?

Comment: Sounds easy enough.  Can you show the code where you have tried to implement this and explain what is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your array, `$array`:

```
$str = '';
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $str .= $k . ':' . $v . ';';
}

echo $str; // 3:15;30:1;1:1;
```

Comment: thanks to all, this is the solution that I use, this doesn't work for me before because the mysql server where i get the array was down, Sorry, I have to stressed by a lot of hours with the php code editor.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one-liner:

```
$array = array(
    3 => 15,
    30 => 1,
    1 => 1,
);

// "3:15;30:1;1:1" ( without last semicolon )
$string = implode( ';', array_map( 
    function($v, $k) { 
        return "$k:$v"; 
    }, $array, array_keys($array) ) 
);

// "3:15;30:1;1:1;" ( with last semicolon  )
$string = implode( array_map( 
    function($v, $k) { 
        return "$k:$v;"; 
    }, $array, array_keys($array) ) 
);
```

Comment: This is easily the best solution, but I think a couple line breaks would make it a lot easier to read.

Comment: Now that I look closer, OP apparently wants `;` after every key-value pair, including the last. You could fix your code to match by removing the first argument to `implode` and changing the callback to return `"$k:$v;"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and easy way to do this.

```
function delimit(&$anArray) {
    $preArray = array();
    foreach($anArray as $key => $value)
        $preArray[] "$key:$value"
    return implode(";", $preArray);
}
```

Edit: This is the way to go if you want to "fence post" the array, meaning you don't want to append an extra semi-colon at the end of the string.